# How to cross-compile OpenSSH for ARM?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling, openssh

I am trying to compile OpenSSH using the Android NDK, but failing.

My attempt consists of the following steps:

1. cross-compile OpenSSL for Android and install headers / libraries to `/home/me/arm`
2. grab OpenSSH 6.2p1 from [here](http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.2p1.tar.gz)
3. extract the archive and run `./configure`:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/home/me/arm \
           --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
           --with-ssl-dir=/home/me/arm
   ```

   ...which resulted in the following error:

   ```
   getrrsetbyname.c:166:2: error: unknown type name 'HEADER'
   ```
4. modify the `./configure` command to include:

   ```
   ac_cv_search_getrrsetbyname=yes
   ```

   ...which fixed the one problem but still aborted with another error:

   ```
   /usr/include/linux/un.h:17:8: error: redefinition of 'struct sockaddr_un'
   ```
5. modify the `./configure` command *again* to include:

   ```
   ac_cv_header_sys_un_h=yes
   ```

   ...which got me even further but *still* aborted with an error:

   ```
   channels.c: In function 'channel_prepare_select':
   channels.c:2143:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'howmany'
   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   channels.c:2145:45: error: 'fd_mask' undeclared (first use in this function)
   ```

Now I'm stuck. I've cracked open Android's `sys/select.h` and discovered that [`fd_mask` isn't defined anywhere](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/select.c#L63). I also was unable to find a `./configure` option to work around this. There's also the issue with `howmany()` being undefined.

What changes do I need to make to get the program to compile?

---

**Edit:** I've managed to get a little bit further now. I've added the following line to `./configure` to get past the "undefined `fd_mask`" error:

```
--with-cflags=-Dfd_mask=int
```

I then received the following error:

```
error: 'struct passwd' has no member named 'pw_gecos'
```

Android's `passwd` struct does not have a `pw_gecos` member. This one was impossible to correct without creating an actual patch for the source code. The patch is [here](https://github.com/nathan-osman/AndroX/blob/ad64b792791e1088e40444037402605e17949865/src/patch/openssh.patch).

I am now stuck with the following error:

```
dns.c: In function 'dns_result_totext':
dns.c:56:7: error: 'ERRSET_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
dns.c:56:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
  function it appears in
dns.c:58:7: error: 'ERRSET_NOMEMORY' undeclared (first use in this function)
...
```

---

**Edit:** I've made some modifications to the patch above that eliminate quite a few of the errors so far. I've also added `ldns`. The configure command now looks like this:

```
patch -p0 <openssh.patch;
autoconf;
./configure --prefix=/home/me/arm \
            --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
            --with-ldns=/home/me/arm \
            --with-ssl-dir=/home/me/arm \
            ac_cv_header_sys_un_h=yes
```

...and [here](https://github.com/nathan-osman/AndroX/blob/811f0c28abf1f9e95d24d79a6d79728025241b04/src/patch/openssh.patch) is the new patch. The errors I get now are:

```
loginrec.c: In function 'construct_utmp':
loginrec.c:665:17: error: 'DEAD_PROCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
loginrec.c:665:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
  each function it appears in
loginrec.c: At top level:
loginrec.c:727:45: warning: 'struct utmpx' declared inside parameter list
  [enabled by default]
```

Comment: See: [DEAD_PROCESS](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp).  Does Android use `utmp`?  You might get things to compile, but they might not work as expected.  This is a *login* file.

Comment: It might be just easier to use android's port (5.9) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+/master or start from studying there.

Comment: I think I'll start submitting parts of my patch to the OpenSSH team.